# How to create a wrapper class that uses session

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

What is the proper way to create a wrapper class for 3rd party library:

I've created a wrapper like so:

```
public class UserContextWrapper
{
     // 3rd party lib
     private UserContext _userContext;

     public string City {
          get { return _userContext.City; }
     }

     public Organization Organization {
          get { return _userContext.Organization; }
     }

     // Create properties that wrap UserContext 3rd party lib properties
}
```

1. Is this the proper way to create wrappers?
2. I need to use (3rd party lib) Organization property which I can not mock because it uses session in it's constructor:

> public class Organization() { // fill in session info };

- How would I handle these types of properties?
- Would I have to create a Wrapper for Organization as well? 
  (OrganizationWrapper => then use that wrapper inside UserContextWrapper?)

Comment: Do you actually _pass_ it the session or just values _from_ the session?  Can you show the _actual_ `Organization` constructor instead of commenting out the parameters?

Comment: Why do you need to warp it?  What functionality are you adding other then the pass-trough parameters you indicate?

Comment: Values from the session are used, not session itself

Comment: So there's no _direct_ dependency on session, so what's the problem mocking it?  I don;t think you have enough detail to give a valid answer.  Maybe show something that _doesn't_ work so we can understand how to fix it?

Comment: Well, when 3rd party lib UserContext() ctor is executed it populates its properties, one of which is Organization. Also, mocking framework MOQ throws an error on Organization because it can't create new Organization() because it's constructor reads from session

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31530165/what-is-best-way-to-wrap-3rd-party-class-c-sharp) helped
Create only those functions that has value with your code and little by little if you need another functions add it up in your wrapper.